# How to avoid directory listing in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel4, I was trying to run laravel4 on a shared hosting.Since I dont have root access, to avoid public in my url. I have moved all the contents in the public directory to "public_html" folder.

Then I changed the locations in respective files. But when I visited url "abc.com/myapp/app", it lists all the folders and files under app directory. Since it exposes the project files, I was looking to avoid the same.

In CodeIgniter if we try to access folders like this it gives message

"Directory access is forbidden."

Edit:

I have added

Options All FollowSymLinks MultiViews -Indexes

in a .htaccess file in the app folder as per suggested by @valey viktorovsky

Comment: are you saying you are just changing /public to /public_html? If so - there *only* thing you change is the paths.php 'public' variable. Everything else should be left as it was.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange when I do localhost/testapp/app, then it lists all the directory and files present in the folder. How can I avoid this.

Comment: It depends on web server. For apache you can add "Options All FollowSymLinks MultiViews -Indexes" to .htaccess

Comment: thanks @ValeryViktorovsky now it shows Access forbidden when I try to open localhost/testapp/app

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple methods...

**The easy one:**
If you have access to .htaccess file and you can modify it, place this little code

```
Options -Indexes
```

**Annoying one**
If you cannot create/modify .htaccess file, create `index.html` file inside each folder you would like to protect