# Redirect to homepage if page is a directory listing in Laravel

Tags: apache, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5.1

I'd like to able able to redirect users (either to a 404 page or back to the homepage) if the page they're at is a directory listing, like so:

[image]

Here is my **.htaccess** file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Is this possible with Laravel? I know you can redirect to specific pages in the app/Exceptions/Handler.php file in case of a specific error, like 404 or 500. Perhaps it's possible to make directories generate an error, and have handler.php do the redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not strictly a Laravel question, directory listing is served directly by Apache and Laravel its not even loaded.

As an easy workaround you can put a bare minimum index.html in the directory and set a meta for redirectione, i.e:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.example.com/example">
```

The better solution would be to configure correctly Apache, you can find some infos [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720947/how-to-avoid-directory-listing-in-laravel-4)

Comment: Right, having an index.html file in the directory prevents directory view, however in this case I'm looking to redirect, not just prevent viewing.

Comment: if inside the index.html there is the meta refresh I wrote above you could redirect where you want

Answer (score 0):

You could do a php redirect using something

```
    <?php
    // PHP permanent URL redirection test
    header("Location: http://www.rapidtables.com/web/dev/php-redirect.htm", true, 301);
    exit();
    ?>
```

Have you seen: [This tutorial?](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/dev/php-redirect.htm)

Comment: This isn't really all that helpful. How would I be able to put a php redirect in a directory listing?

Comment: As in dparoli's answer, you can make the php script run when index.html is opened